# Simple db mongo query gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

Hey I am trying to query the database (mongodb) from my index.js file then return the value from the query into a variable so I can then use that variable to show the persons information on the website. I currently have this code up but it is giving me problems. Trying to figure out how to query it the right way. I am querying the email but I want to extract the first name based on an email query. I am using node.js and jade for my view engine.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test5');

var user = function (name) { 
    var name = db.users.find({ email: 'works@gmail.com' }).pretty();
    console.log(name); 
    return name;
};

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Weblio', user: user});
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using Mongoose, so what I'd suggest is that you use their querying functions which have worked well for me in the past. It also helps to establish Mongoose models for your data stored in MongoDB.

Try this (note: it is untested, but I pulled it from a functioning program):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test5');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, index: true },
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        email: "someone@something.com"
    }, function(err, user) {
       if(err) {
           res.send(err);
       } else {
           console.log(user.firstName);
           res.render('index', {title: 'Weblio', user: user.firstName});
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked, yeah I had a user model was not sure if I could just use it like that. Is it better to do a res.send(err) or req.send(500)?

Comment: It's up to you, whether you want the user to see the error or not. You could do `res.send(500)` to the user, and maybe `console.log(err)` so you can see it.

Comment: Makes sense, what is best practice for this situation or the route people usually take?

Comment: I like to display clean errors to my users, so I would probably log it and display something nice on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all IO in node is asynchronous which means that your find method isn't going to return the actual result but a promise or it is expecting a callback that it will call with the result.

Try this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test5');


exports.index = function(req, res) {
  db.users.find({ email: 'works@gmail.com' }, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      return req.send(500);
      }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Weblio', user: JSON.stringify(data)});
    });
};
```

Comment: Is findOne better than find, what is the difference between the two calls assuming that what you are searching for is unique, and that you are searching for only one user?

Comment: `findOne` simply returns the first result it finds, rather than searching the entire collection. I believe you can set a limit using just the regular `find` query too. In the case of searching by email address, they are most likely unique, so it makes sense to just return the first one it finds. But it really depends on your data set.

Comment: Ok also, is this a smart way to query the db whenever you want to pull up a user's profile info on a page? What I am ultimately trying to do is to take a cookie from a user that logs in and use the email to query his info and show him his info on a userprofile page. I am using backbone too so is it better to fetch the info from backbone instead of querying like this would be the question.